# Projective norm and different representations

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and consider their projective tensor product $Z$.
It is easy to show that for any $x \in X, y \in Y$ we have
\begin{equation}
\left \Vert x \otimes y \right \Vert = \left \Vert x \right \Vert \left \Vert y \right \Vert
\end{equation}
which tells us that for simple tensor products we do not need to consider representations with more than one summand.

I was wondering if this is a more general property: Suppose we have
\begin{equation}
z = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_k \otimes y_k = \sum_{k = 1}^{n+1} x'_k \otimes y'_k
\end{equation}
for some $z \in Z$. Is it then always true that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \left \Vert x_k \right \Vert \left \Vert y_k \right \Vert \le \sum_{k = 1}^{n+1} \left \Vert x'_k \right \Vert \left \Vert y'_k \right \Vert
\end{equation}

For $n = 1$ this is clearly true but I fail to see if this holds more generally.

Comment: Of course not. If you added $x_{n+1}=y_{n+1}=x_{n+2}=y_{n+2}=0$, you would get the reverse inequality. But easy examples show that this is not always an equality. To be more precise, you can write $0=x\otimes x-x\otimes x=0\otimes 0+0\otimes 0+0\otimes 0$ with $x\neq 0$.